# "Type mismatch in parameter" when using setfillpattern()?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks, turbo-c++, bgi

I have started working on a C project to build a PacMan game, but I am getting an error when I execute below code. The error is generated by Code::Blocks as well as Turbo C++ 3.5.
In Code::Blocks I remove the path which is `"C:\TurboC3\BGI"`,but the error still continues.

Error in Turbo C++
[image: Turbo C++ error]

Error in Code::Blocks
[image: Error in Code::Blocks]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
int main()
{
    int gd=0,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TurboC3\\BGI");
    setfillpattern(SOLID_FILL,YELLOW);
    circle(200,100,10);
    line(200,250,200,250);
    line(225,250,225,250);
    line(250,250,250,250);
    line(275,250,275,250);
    line(300,250,300,250);
    line(325,250,325,250);
    arc(50,225,110,-100,30);
    printf("Hello...Let's Play PacMan !! \n\n");
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: Turbo C++? BGI? I think you should take a look at the calendar. Its the wrong millennia.

Comment: I have Added Error images @JohnnyMopp you can now refer to them.

Comment: Check the prototype: [setfillpattern(char *upattern, int color)](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setfillpattern.html).

Comment: Please can you elaborate your comment ?, I'm facing difficulty understanding it. @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Where is `SOLID_FILL` defined?  It's obviously not the type that `setfillpattern` expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use BGI, but a quick search finds that [`setfillpattern`](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setfillpattern.html) is expecting a `char` array as the first parameter, but `SOLID_FILL` is of type `enum fill_styles`. To use `SOLID_FILL` you need to call [`setfillstyle`](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setfillstyle.html) instead.

To use `setfillpattern` you need to supply a custom pattern:

```
char pattern[8] = {0x00, 0x70, 0x20, 0x27, 0x24, 0x24, 0x07, 0x00};
setfillpattern(pattern, YELLOW);
```